# RWD page embed in frameset without meta viewport

Tags: dns, responsive-design, viewport, redirect, frameset

I made a RWD page with meta viewport, but it was embed in frameset, and the outer frameset page doesn't have meta viewport. so the RWD page become out of control.

But I don't have premission to edit the frameset page.

Is there any solution?